# Вложенное меню clip-path

Tags: html, css

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atomr/aqv1wvfk/)

Как можно реализовать подобное меню?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально видно только первый верхний блок с элементами, при клике на элемент - открывается нижний, при клике на один элемент из второго блока - открывается правый блок
Cверстал пока что так:

```
<ul class="first">
        <li class="first-link">
          <a href="#">
            <span>Умная страна</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="second">
            <li class="second-link">
              <a href="#">
                <span>Развитие</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="third">
                <li><a href="#"><span>Уровень шума</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><span>Взаимодействия</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><span>Расширение</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><span>Информация</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><span>Контроль</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><span>Экология</span></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><span>Энергия</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span>Умный город</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span>Умное предприятие</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span>Умный дом</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span>Я</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Использовал маску в виде:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 1%, 0 0, 50% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(100% 1%, 0 0, 50% 100%);
```

Получилось примерно следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.к. второе и третье меню будет вложено, то маска обрезает и внутренние элементы. absolute/relative/z-index конечно же, не помогает

Comment: Первое, не усложняйте себе жизнь с `clip-path`. Проще всего с `background` это все реализовать (кроссбраузерность будет выше и адаптивность прикрутить можно будет). Второе, не вкладывайте второе и третье меню в первый список. Лучше добавить немного JS для открытия нужных подпунктов (опять же из-за удобства дальнейшей работы, чтоб избежать абсолютного позиционирования).

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev То есть, сделать все отдельными независимыми блоками и связать data атрибутами? И как с помощью background можно сделать такой фон, можете подсказать?

Comment: Именно так, независимые блоки и data-атрибуты. По поводу фона, все зависит от того, будет ли данный элемент масштабироваться. Если все статично, то, задайте фиксированные размеры и "порежьте" фон. Лично я бы все равно не возился с картинками, а использовал границы. Сейчас приделаю пример.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev хорошо, буду ждать. На счет "порезать" фон не смог найти нужной инфы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Учитывая, что все равно будете использовать JS, прикрутил наведение на него. Принцип поймете. Можно использовать пседвоелемнты и делать треугольники фоном.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('li').click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  top: -34px;
  width: 120px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}

[class^="level-"] {
  border-top: 50px solid #ffdbcb;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #483939;
}

[class^="level-"].active {
  border-top: 50px solid #ff3920;
  color: #fff;
}

.level-1 {
  width: 0;
}

.level-2 {
  width: 160px;
}

.level-3 {
  width: 240px;
}

.level-4 {
  width: 320px;
}

.level-5 {
  width: 400px;
}

.level-6 {
  width: 480px;
}

.level-7 {
  width: 560px;
}

.level-8 {
  width: 640px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="top">
  <li class="level-8"><span>Умная страна</span></li>
  <li class="level-7"><span>Взаимодействия</span></li>
  <li class="level-6"><span>Расширение</span></li>
  <li class="level-5"><span>Информация</span></li>
  <li class="level-4"><span>Контроль</span></li>
  <li class="level-3"><span>Экология</span></li>
  <li class="level-2"><span>Энергия</span></li>
  <li class="level-1"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое